# pytest WinError 123 in conda virtual environment

Tags: python, windows-10, pytest, conda

My question is probably related to

[Pytest : OSError: [WinError 123] launching pytest on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1472030/pytest-oserror-winerror-123-launching-pytest-on-windows-10)

But this question did not receive any answers, so I will describe the problem again:

I open my Anaconda prompt, navigate to my project directory *proj-dir*, and run *pytest*.

The result differs depending on my previous settings:

1. If my standard base Python 3.7.3 installation is activated, everything works fine.
2. If another myenv conda environment is activated, I get a long list of errors. the last one being

> OSError: [WinError 123] The syntax for filename, directory name, or
>   volume label is incorrect: 'c:\folder1\proj-dir\
>   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'

I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me? My Python version is 3.7.3 and the operating system is Windows 10.

EDIT: SOLVED. I HAD A PYTHONPATH VARIABLE. DELETING IT SOLVED THE PROBLEM.

Comment: Please include the full strack track. Also `conda list` of your environments that work and do not work would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean with "full strack track"?

Comment: conda list produces a list which is much too long to post it here...

Comment: Sorry, meant stack trace. The whole long error message you get, not just the final part.

Comment: Ok, I added the full error message.

Comment: I'd try reinstalling pytest. Or recreating the environment. Something seems strange with paths or dependencies.

Comment: I did that and now also the base installation throws the same error. Even importing the package throws the error so there seems to be something wrong with the installation of pytest.

Comment: I had an environment variable PYTHONPATH pointing to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

I know that it is not recommended to set this but obviously I did some time ago. Deleting the variable solved the problem. Thanks, Kyle!